# Two python packages with the same structure use function of the same name from other package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, python-packaging

I have created 2 packages, named A and B. Both packages have the same structure to them, as they do very similar things, e.g. their structure looks like this:

```
A/
  __init__.py
  subpackage1/
    __init__.py
    submodule1.py
  subpackage2/
    __init__.py
    submodule2.py
  setup.py
  README.md
  requirements.txt
```

They share the same subpackage, submodule and function names. Each module has a main function, which does the argparsing for me and calls a function with those params. In my setup.py, I specified additional entry points, so that I can call the modules from the command line:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.readlines() 

setuptools.setup(
    name="A",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Me",
    author_email="me@myself.com",
    description="Test package",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    entry_points ={
        'console_scripts': [
            'command1 = subpackage1.submodule1:main',
            'command2 = subpackage2.submodule2:main'
        ]
    },
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires = requirements
)
```

When I install the package in a blank docker container, it works fine and I can call my functions with 'command1' and 'command2' from the command line.

As stated before, package B has exactly the same setup.py file, except for the name. If I install that as well, the package A now uses the entry points of package B instead of its own. That means, I call the function with the right name, but from the wrong package.

I want to have them side-by-side in my docker container. How do I have to adjust my packages, so that the system can differentiate between them?

I installed the packages via pip from wheels that I generated.

Comment: First impression, the directory structure seems wrong: the first red flag is that there shouldn't be a `__init__.py` in the same directory as `setup.py`, the second red flag is that the directories next to `setup.py` can not be _sub-packages_, they should be _top-level packages_.

Comment: @sinoroc I removed the top-level `__init__.py` (which I actually added out of frustration shortly before posting  tbh). Same result as before. Thanks for clarifying terminology!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First impression, the directory structure seems wrong: the first red flag is that there shouldn't be a `__init__.py` in the same directory as `setup.py`, the second red flag is that the directories next to `setup.py` can not be *sub-packages*, they are *top-level packages*.

In your example the top-level packages are `subpackage1` and `subpackage2` in the project `A`, and in the project `B` as well. So in both cases, after installation the importable items are `import subpackage1` and `import subpackage2`. It also means that when you install `A`, then `B`, the top-level packages of `B` overwrite those that were previously installed as part of `A` (since they have the exact same name).

What you probably want to do is to add a directory `a` in the project `A` right next to its `setup.py`, and move both `subpackageN` as well as the `__init__.py` into that `a` directory (same in the project `B`). So that directory structure looks like:

```
A/
  a/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
      __init__.py
      submodule1.py
    subpackage2/
      __init__.py
      submodule2.py
  setup.py
  README.md
  requirements.txt
```

Then the imports will look like:

```py
import a.subpackage1
import b.subpackage1

from a import subpackage2 as subpackagea2
from b import subpackage2 as subpackageb2
```

Following that the `setup.py` files should be adjusted accordingly:

```py
# ...

setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    entry_points ={
        'console_scripts': [
            'commanda1 = a.subpackage1.submodule1:main',
            'commanda2 = a.subpackage2.submodule2:main'
        ]
    },
)
```

Comment: This solved my problem. For some reason, I completely missed this option when designing the package. Thanks!