# setup.py is installing into the root of folder site-packages

Tags: python, git, installation, pip, python-packaging

Yes, I'm new to Python packaging but not new to Python. A package I have developed has subpackages - say 'formats' and 'toolbox'. My code is in a repository under Gitlab. The server's address is https://git.wur.nl

On my computer I have several Python instances. To be sure I invoke the right instance of pip, I move to where it is installed - in subfolder Scripts. To install my package on my Windows machine, I therefore type:
C:\Python36\Scripts\pip install git+https://git.wur.nl/myname/mypkg

The installation then seems to go well. I'd expect that my code would end up in directory C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\mypkg, i.e. with subfolders 'formats' and 'toolbox' below folder mypkg. Unfortunately, the folders 'formats' and 'toolbox' end up in the root of C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages. When I try to import mypkg in a Python script or so, I'm told that package mypkg does not exist - no surprise. Below is the code of module setup.py ...

What is going wrong here?

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os

PACKAGE = "mypkg"
NAME = "Mypkg"
DESCRIPTION = 'Python raster GIS library with low memory requirements.' 
AUTHOR = "Dobedani"
AUTHOR_EMAIL = 'dobedani@xyz.nl'
URL = 'https://git.wur.nl/myname/mypkg/'
LICENSE="LGPL"
VERSION = "1.0"

here = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

long_description = 'Python raster GIS library with low memory requirements.'

setup(
    name=NAME,
    version=VERSION,
    url=URL,
    download_url='https://git.wur.nl/dobedani/mypkg/-/archive/master/mypkg-master.tar.gz',
    license='LGPL',
    author=AUTHOR,
    install_requires=['pyshp>=2.1.0',
                      'pyproj>=1.9.5.1',
                      'numpy>=1.14.3',
                      'tifffile>=2019.3.18',
                      'tables>=3.5.2',
                      'netCDF4>=1.5.1.2',
                      'libtiff>=0.4.2'],
    author_email=AUTHOR_EMAIL,
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    long_description=long_description,
    packages=find_packages(), 
    include_package_data=True,
    platforms='any',
    test_suite='mypkg.tests.make_test_suite',
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU Lesser General Public License v3.0 (LGPL 3.0)',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering']
)
```

The following gives an idea of the structure of the package:

```
mypkg  
  formats/
    __init__.py
    asciigrid.py
  toolbox/
    __init__.py
    cliplib.py
  setup.py
  README.md
  requirements.txt
  MANIFEST.in
  LICENSE
```

Comment: sounds like the instance of `pip` you are using is not attached to the version you think it is. you should just point it at the python version and do `python -m pip install <whatever you want>`

Comment: You should show your directory structure. But my guess you have the same issue as in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64159288/11138259 -- You got confused about top-level packages. You probably need to move all your code into a `mypkg` folder, etc.-- See my answer to the other question.

Comment: I have added the structure of the package below the text which I entered earlier.

Comment: Alright, it confirms my suspicions. If you want your top level package to be `mypkg` as in `import mypkg` or `from mypkg import toolbox`, then you need to put all your code in a `mypkg` directory directly next to your `setup.py`.

Comment: @sinoroc I used the package of a colleague as example. His setup.py is working well. What you are recommending looks ... well ... not elegant to me - almost ugly. Hence I found it hard to accept. However, I had another look at the project of my colleague and I have seen he has actually done the same. So apparently, this is it. Thanks!

Comment: What is ugly about that? Probably you are mixing name of project, name of top level packages, name of project directory. Those are different things and can have different names. In your case you want to have the same name for project directory (source code repository), name of the project, and name of the top level package. So it looks like there is a lot of repetition maybe, but that's because you reuse the same name everywhere (`mypkg`), you don't have to. Or what is bothering you?

Comment: @sinoroc What you are saying is true. Nevertheless I establish that it is required to have a folder for the project and another one for the top-level package - whatever names you use. Not everybody will see the need for this distinction. And the main disadvantage is that there's an extra level in the folder hierarchy. Why do I have to go deeper? Good programmers are said to be lazy.

Comment: You are the one adding the levels `formats` and `toolbox`, you could get rid of those. Or put all your code in one single Python module, I guess... It's matter of point of view. -- Anyway, in all seriousness: files such as `setup.py`, `MANIFEST.in` are not part of the code, per-se, so it is good that they are separated from the rest. I think this structure is good, but I usually even add one more layer of separation by using the _`src` layout_.

Answer (score 1):

There is confusion about what the *top level* packages of the project are.

If you want the top level package to be `mypkg` and the code to be importable like in the following:

```py
import mypkg
# or
from mypkg import formats
from mypkg import toolbox
```

then the appropriate directory structure is:

```
mypkg/
  mypkg/
    __init__.py
    formats/
      __init__.py
      asciigrid.py
    toolbox/
      __init__.py
      cliplib.py
  setup.py
  README.md
  requirements.txt
  MANIFEST.in
  LICENSE
```

Comment: @Dobedani Does that answer your question? Anything else that needs to be clarified?